# ajax post data to PHP from tinyMCE text field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have a text field TinyMCE 4.0 i when i am posting html from this field using ajax i seem to be having a problem with the data not ending up server side

in Firefox firebug it shows i posted this data

```
 attendanceID=&noteID=&Category=2&date=20-May-2014&leave=<p>&nbsp;</p> <p>fxghdfhdsfhsdfhsdf</p>&prn=15407&act=edit
```

server side PHP

```
  print_r( $_POST['leave']);
```

It prints

```
 <p>
```

but when i post this

```
  attendanceID=&noteID=&Category=2&date=20-May-2014&leave=<p>fadsfdasfasdf</p>&prn=15418&act=edit
```

everything works as expected prints

```
 <p>fadsfdasfasdf</p>
```

Comment: looks like you need to encode the ampersand character in your query string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your post parameters URL encoded.

Try

[encodeURIComponent for javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)

or

[rawurlencode for PHP](https://www.php.net/rawurlencode)

Answer (score 3):

You need to have it properly url encoded. It hits `&nbsp;` and thinks you've started a new variable.

This question has some more detailed information - [When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)

If it's data that someone else is providing to you, you should use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on each url parameter. This prevents them from sending something to the server you're not expecting.

Note:
There is also [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) which encodes the whole URI, ignoring some characters that have meaning to the url.

Instead of `leave=<p>&nbsp;` you should have `leave=%20`

`%20` is the url encoded value for a space